# ¿Por qué un segundo IF que se cumple no muestra mensaje de alerta?

Tags: javascript

Debo comparar los grados de unos infractores a ser sancionados, donde entre menor sea el número, mayor sera su grado, por lo tanto deben cumplirse las siguiente condiciones:

- El superior no puede tener un grado inferior al sancionador.
- El superior no puede tener un grado inferior al sancionado.
- El sancionador no puede tener un grado inferior al sancionado.

Es decir que también se debe cumplir:

- El superior debe tener un grado mayor o igual al sancionador.
- El superior debe tener un grado mayor al sancionado.
- El sancionador debe tener un grado mayor al sancionado.

**Recuerden que: A mayor número menor es el grado**

Un ejemplo funcional sería:

```
sancionado: 7
sancionador: 6
superior: 6 ó 5.
```

El problema es que al validar el primer `if`, el resto ya no se ejecuta, la única forma es que se no se cumpla el primer `if` para ejecutar el segundo, y que no se valide ni el primero ni el segundo para que se ejecute el tercer `if`.

Es decir que si el sancionador tiene un grado menor al sancionado dirá el primer error pero no el resto.

Aquí les dejo el código:

```js
function validar() {
var sancionado = document.getElementById("sancionado");
var sancionador = document.getElementById("sancionador");
var superior = document.getElementById("superior");
var mensaje = "";
alert("Sancionado: " + sancionado.value);
alert("Sancionador: " + sancionador.value);
alert("Superior: " + superior.value);




if (sancionador.value > sancionado.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    sancionado.value = 0;
    sancionador.value = 0;
    alert("El sancionador no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionado");

}

if (superior.value > sancionado.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    superior.value = 0;
    sancionado.value = 0;
    alert("El superior no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionaDO");

}

if (superior.value > sancionador.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    superior.value = 0;
    sancionador.value = 0;
    alert("El superior no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionaDOR");
}

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sancionado">Sancionado<br>
<input type="text" id="sancionador">Sancionador<br>
<input type="text" id="superior">Superior<br>

<input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="validar();">
```

Quisiera que se validaran todos los 'If' uno a uno, y que hicieran cero los valores como tengo en el codigo.

**Si usamos 1 , 4 y 5, Deberian saltar los tres mensajes**

Comment: En la descripción de lo que hace el código no se menciona que cada `if` modifica los valores.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No se validan el resto de if porque el alert corta la ejecución del método de validación, podrías probar a tener variables de control y ejecutar solo un alert. Algo como:

```
<input type="text" id="sancionado">Sancionado<br>
<input type="text" id="sancionador">Sancionador<br>
<input type="text" id="superior">Superior<br>

<input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="validar();">


</body>
<script>
function validar() {
var sancionado = document.getElementById("sancionado").value;
var sancionador =  document.getElementById("sancionador").value;
var superior =  document.getElementById("superior").value;
var msj = "";
alert("Sancionado: "+sancionado);
alert("Sancionador: "+sancionador);
alert("Superior: "+superior);

if (sancionador > sancionado) {
    msj = "El sancionador no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionado \n";
}

if (superior > sancionado) {
    msj += "El superior  no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionado \n";
}

if (superior > sancionador) {
  msj+= "El superior  no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionador \n"
}
    alert(msj);
}
</script>
</html>
```

Se puede refinar mucho mas poniendo una escala para que mensaje quieres motrar cuando se cumplan más condiciones, etc

Comment: al hacerlo asi si la primera condicion se cumple guarda el mensaje pero luego si la segunda tambien se cumple sustituye el mensaje mostrando solo el segundo mensaje

Comment: en ese caso puedes ir concatenando los mensajes

Comment: @FederHico creo que ya se que pasaba, faltaban puntos y comas en los alert, ahora muestran los tres mensajes

Comment: de todos modos, pareciera que estás debugueando con alerts. Usa console.log("msj");  y mira la consola en las herramientas de desarrollo.

Comment: @FederHico sigue sin funcionar solo se cumplen ahora las dos primeras condiciones, como puedo frenar los IF ? usando event.preventalert? que se ejecuten uno a la vez

Comment: ahí edité ésta respuesta para que concatene los mensajes, creo que te puede ayudar

Comment: @FederHico agregue unas modificaciones a la pregunta

Comment: El tercer if con los datos que entrada que tienes no se puede cumplir nunca, superior 6 o 5 nunca va a ser mayor que sancionador 6 - tendría que ser mayor o igual para que entrara en el caso de que superior fuera 6

Answer (score 2):

El problema está en que estás modificando los valores de las variables a las que estas pasando los datos de entrada antes de terminar de realizar todas las evaluaciones. He convertido a comentario las líneas de código que hace eso, para que veas que al usar como datos de entra 1, 4 y 5 se mostrarán las alertas correspondientes a cada `if`.

```js
function validar() {
var sancionado = document.getElementById("sancionado");
var sancionador = document.getElementById("sancionador");
var superior = document.getElementById("superior");
var mensaje = "";
alert("Sancionado: " + sancionado.value);
alert("Sancionador: " + sancionador.value);
alert("Superior: " + superior.value);




if (sancionador.value > sancionado.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //sancionado.value = 0;
    //sancionador.value = 0;
    alert("El sancionador no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionado");

}

if (superior.value > sancionado.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //superior.value = 0;
    //sancionado.value = 0;
    alert("El superior no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionaDO");

}

if (superior.value > sancionador.value) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //superior.value = 0;
    //sancionador.value = 0;
    alert("El superior no puede ser de grado inferior al sancionaDOR");
}

}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="sancionado">Sancionado<br>
<input type="text" id="sancionador">Sancionador<br>
<input type="text" id="superior">Superior<br>

<input type="button" value="calcular" onclick="validar();">
```

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que entiendo de la jerarquía lógica de tu enunciado quedaría así:

> *superior > sancionador > sancionado*

Después de esto, no entiendo el significado de **event.preventDefault()** aquí dado que no le pasas un parámetro a la función llamado **'event'**. Deduzco que habrás visto en otros lugares como al enviar un formulario usan esta característica en algún trozo de código y es básicamente para evitar el comportamiento por defecto de un evento *(como puede ser una etiqueta 'a' o el refresco de tu página al hacer un 'submit')*.

Aquí en tu caso para lo que quieres no te haría falta, ya que tu botón HTML solo dispara una función. Además, tienes una variable mensaje que no utilizas, que de nuevo deduzco, era para utilizarlo en cada condicional.

```
    function validar() {

     var sancionado = document.getElementById("sancionado");
     var sancionador = document.getElementById("sancionador");
     var superior = document.getElementById("superior");

     var mensaje = "";

     //Logica del programa 
     superior < sancionado ? mensaje = "El superior no puede ser menor que el 
          sancionado y el sancionador" : sancionador < sancionado ?  
        mensaje = " El sancionador no puede ser menor que el sancionado" :
        mensaje = " el superior no puede ser menor que el sancionador " 

        alert(mensaje);
   }
```

Sabiendo la lógica de comparación desde el principio podemos simplificar nuestro código y avanzar mas rápido que si nos pusiéramos a codificar directamente, para los condicionales he utilizado los operadores ternarios a los que les puedes echar un vistazo en: [Operadores Ternarios](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Operadores/Conditional_Operator).

Un saludo, y ABC *(Always Be Coding)*